# Create lists by comparing existing lists in python and export to excel

Tags: python, excel, list, for-loop, venn-diagram

I am working on the python script trying to create the excel file with columns in the following way:

a only

b only

c only

a and b but not in c

b and c but not in a

c and a but not in b

a and b and c.

The output would look like a 3 group venn diagram but i need in lists,and then i can export to excel spreadsheet.

```
list1 = ['ab','cd','gfa','eha','tu','asb','acd','cgf','ceh','dtu','ased','ra','re','sdgfsycbjs','jcjhcbsd']
list2 = ['abx','cd','gfr','eha','tu','asb','acl','cgfta','cpah','adtu','assa','fd','as','sbddsvc','jbcbh']
list3 = ['abs','cd','gfv','eh','tu','asb','ased','cgf','ceh','adtu','assa','qw','uy','hdsjb','bcjh']
a = []
b = []
c = []
ab = []
bc = []
ca = []
abc = []
for item in list1:
        if item in list2:
            if item in list3:
                if item not in abc:
                    abc.append(item)
            else:
                ab.append(item)
        else:
            if item not in ca:
                a.append(item)

for item in list2:
    if item in list3:
        if item in list1:
            if item not in abc:
                abc.append(item)
        else:
            bc.append(item)
    else:
        if item not in ab:
            b.append(item)        

for item in list3:
    if item in list1:
        if item in list2:
            if item not in abc:
                abc.append(item)
        else:
            ca.append(item)
    else:
        if item not in bc:
            c.append(item)
```

Comment: I edited the code. but some values are being repeated, for example: the value eha is in both a and b. and we know that a should be a only and it should not appear in a but it is being appended.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are `set`s, not lists.  They support these sort of operations very well.  To make sets, either call `set(xs)` on a list `xs`, or use a set literal like `{'a', 'b', ... }` (as opposed to a similar list literal using square brackets).

With these sets, you can do things like

```
foo = {'a', 'b'}
bar = {'b', 'c', 'd'}

foo.difference(bar) # returns {'a'}
foo.union(bar) # returns {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
foo.intersection(bar) # returns {'b'}
foo.symmetric_difference(bar) # returns {'a', 'c', 'd'}
...
```

You can also convert back to lists by calling `list(foo)` or similar.  With these tools, you can easily build up the venn diagrams you desire.  Note that all these functions return *new* sets, never modifying the originals.